# I am unable to change the directory in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, directory, command-prompt

cmd is not able to change the directory using the command

```
C:\Windows\system32>CD I:
```

It is going back to same C: directory

The screenshot [image]

Answer (score 3):

Just type "I:" and press Enter, then use "CD foldername" to dive into your folders.

Answer (score 2):

#### The short answer

The correct commando to go from `C:\Windows\system32` to `I:\`, is this :

```
cd /d i:\
```

---

#### More details

If you're somewhere random on your `I:\` drive, and you want to go to the root of your drive, you can use this command :

```
cd i:\
```

If you're somewhere random on your `I:\` drive, and you want to go to a specific folder on your drive, you can use this command :

```
cd i:\path\to\my\folder
```

If you're on a different drive, and you want to go to the root of your `I:\` drive, you can use this command :

```
cd /d i:\
```

If you're on a different drive, and you want to go to a specific folder on your `I:` drive, you can use this command :

```
cd /d i:\path\to\my\folder
```

If you're on a different drive, and you want to go to the last open folder of you `I:` drive, you can use this command :

```
cd /d i:
```

As a shorthand for `cd /d i:`, you can also use this command :

```
i:
```

Answer (score 0):

Read `cd /?`  to learn there is a `/d` switch to change drive and directory at the same time

Keep in mind that a

```
cd I:\
```

would have an effect even if the current drive would not change .

An alternative would be

```
pushd "I:\"
```

which stores the current location on a stack and can be recalled lateron with

```
popd
```